# "as it would be natural" or "as would be natural"?

Tags: grammar, subjects

I recently had a paper reviewed and, among other things, one of the reviewers said that I should replace the sentence "as it would be natural" by "as would be natural".

The whole whole sentence on the paper is

> This implies that a user cannot take advantage of the low number 
>   of states to make the homomorphic evaluation faster, as it would be natural.

I have the impression that the clause would lack a subject if I wrote it without the pronoun "it". Could you please tell me which of the two options are more appropriate?

Comment: Presumably it was a paper you wrote, so you know the intended meaning. It is unclear what the "**it**" in the sentence refers to, but without, "as would be natural" refers to "take advantage of ..." (the usual way it would be done).

Comment: @WeatherVane I am trying to say that one would expect to be possible for a user to take advantage of the low number of states to speed up the evaluation. Maybe I will just rewrite the whole sentence...

Comment: The reviewer is correct: remove the "**it**".